# how to mix links ( <a> tag ) and headings ( <h1> tag ) in web standard?

Tags: html, web-standards

What is the correct code to create a link with heading 1 according to web standards?

is it

```
<h1><a href="http://stackoverflow.com"> stackoverflow </a></h1>
```

or

```
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com"><h1> stackoverflow </h1></a>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 161, accepted):

According to web standards you aren't allowed to put block elements into inline elements.

As `h1` is a block element and `a` is an inline element the correct way is:

```
<h1><a href="#">This is a title</a></h1>
```

Here is a link so you can learn more: [w3 Visual formatting model](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html)

However, there is an exception that in HTML5 it is valid to wrap block-level elements (like `div`, `p` or `h*`) in anchor tags. Wrapping block-level elements in inline elements other than anchors still goes against the standards.

Comment: In HTLM5 this has changed. Both examples will validate - http://validator.w3.org/.

Comment: nice one. its an easy mistake to make, and while both will validate its logical that naturally inline elements should be descendants of block level elements.

Comment: @pushplaybang - I would say it's more semantic to wrap the header in a link unless only part of the header is supposed to be clickable (I can't think of a use-case for that).  Regardless, it's nice both are supported in html5.

Answer (score 51):

HTML5 updates this subject: it is now OK to wrap block-level elements with A's, as stated under another question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9782054/674965 and here: http://davidwalsh.name/html5-elements-links

Comment: This answer is now much more relevant than the accepted answer

Comment: @JoshDavenport The accepted answer has been updated to reflect that

Answer (score 7):

`a > h1` will cause difficulty in selecting text

[image: Text Selection Issues]

Since both are completely valid in HTML5, it is better to use `h1 > a`

Answer (score 2):

As far as I understand HTML5 does allow you to wrap block level elements in link tags. However, bugs may show up in older browsers. I encountered this with Firefox 3.6.18 and got moz-rs-heading="" inserted into my code. Thus my styles broke. If you care about a work around, you can then wrap the link tags in divs. The following provides a better explanation of why the additional code works http://oli.jp/2009/html5-block-level-links/