# How do I enclose <h3> inside <a>

Tags: html, element, nav

My professor in an assignment wants us to list our education by colleges/highschools. He specifically states "Enclose the above `<h3>` inside of an `<a>` element with the fully qualified URL of the school’s main  website as the href and set the target attribute to _blank. By enclose, I mean place the `<a>` tag immediately before the `<h3>` and the `</a>` immediately after the `</h3>`." I do exactly as stated and it does not work, and creates a "target ="_blank" text below two other `<a>` elements in `<nav>`. This line of code is written in `<main>`.

I expected a `<h3>` that is hyperlinked to my University homepage, that displays my University name on it.

Comment: Please include your HTML as you've written it. There's no reason it wouldn't work. It can be made into an executable snippet as well. Please see the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page.

Comment: Tangential: SO didn't delete any of your text; it interpreted it as HTML tags because it wasn't properly formatted. The help icon in the editor provides formatting info and links to the [advanced help page](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code).

Comment: I know the assignment asked you to put `<h3>` inside of `<a>`, but FYI it's better to put `<h3>` **outside** of `<a>`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62291557/13138364

Answer (score -1):

Did you do it like this?

```html
<a href="https://github.com/" target="_blank">
  <h3>GitHub</h3>
</a>

<a href="https://stackoverflow.com/" target="_blank">
  <h3>Stack Overflow</h3>
</a>

<a href="https://www.linkedin.com/feed/" target="_blank">
  <h3>LinkedIn</h3>
</a>
```

I've tested and it worked; if that's not it, please provide more details and i'll try to help you.